# Read csv file with nodejs with a max number rows

Tags: javascript, node.js, filestream, node-csv-parse

I'm trying to read a CSV file with `node.js` using the `csv-parser`  library.

Since it's a big file, I need to check the header and the first `100` rows and the stop the method and return `true` if everything is ok or `false` if the data doesn't respect the condition.

How can I achieve this?

This is what I have so far:

```js
const csv = require('csv-parser');
const fs = require('fs');    
exports.checkFileFormat = (file) => {
  let stream = fs.createReadStream(file.tempFilePath)
    .pipe(csv())
    .on('headers', (headers) => {
      /*...some logic...*/
    })
    .on('data', (row) => {
      if (!typeof (row["USAGE"]) == 'number'
          || !moment(row["START_DATE"], 'YYYYMMDD', true).isValid()
          || !moment(row["END_DATE"], 'YYYYMMDD', true).isValid()) {
        stream.unpipe(csv());
        return false;
      }       
    })
    .on('end', () => {
       console.log('CSV file successfully processed');
    });
    return true;
}
```

In a previous version I had also declared: `var num = 100` and tested it inside `.on('data', (row) => {...}` but it didn't work.

Comment: make the function `checkFileFormat ` return a promise. Inside the promise, `resolve(false)` instead of `return false` and `resolve(true)` in the `'.on('end')` callback. I'm not completely sure this will work, but that's how I would approach it

Comment: I've personally tested my answer and it works as expected. The only problem was in the `stream.close()` function, which apparently doesn't exist

Answer (score 2):

Following up from my comment

make the function `checkFileFormat`  return a promise. Inside the promise, `resolve(false)` instead of `return false` and `resolve(true)` in the `'.on('end')` callback. I'm not completely sure this will work, but that's how I would approach it

```
const csv = require('csv-parser');
const fs = require('fs');

exports.checkFileFormat = (file) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let stream = fs.createReadStream(file.tempFilePath)
            .pipe(csv())
            .on('headers', (headers) => {
                /*...some logic...*/
            })
            .on('data', (row) => {
                if (!typeof (row["USAGE"]) == 'number'
                    || !moment(row["START_DATE"], 'YYYYMMDD', true).isValid()
                    || !moment(row["END_DATE"], 'YYYYMMDD', true).isValid()) {
                    stream.end(); // stream.unpipe(csv());
                    resolve(false);
                }
            })
            .on('end', () => {
                console.log('CSV file successfully processed');
                resolve(true);
            });
    });    
}
```

Comment: Out of curiousity - does this really work? You're unpiping a new `csv`-stream from `stream` when the condition is reached.

Comment: well i'm not sure about the `unpipe` part, that was included in the OPs original code so I assumed he figured that part out himself. Everything else about this works, namely the `Promise` mechanisms. I've used this code in a real example and it spits out the correct results. But no, I don't know if `unpipe(csv())` is the right thing to do there to close the stream.

Comment: Thank you for your hint. I'm trying to combine the Promise with @eol code. Indeed `unpipe(csv())` doesn't work as expected, when i upload a second file, right after  the first one, i get `[ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END]: write after end`.

Comment: @llandino for the record, rather than `stream.unpipe(csv())`, I think @eol is right that `stream.end()` is preferrable. Other than that, this answer is correct. I'll edit it to include `stream.end()`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to read a certain amount of lines and then break, you can try the following:

```
const csv = require('csv-parser');
const fs = require('fs');
let count = 0;
let maxLines = 3;
let fsStream = fs.createReadStream('./data.csv');
let csvStream = csv();

fsStream.pipe(csvStream)
    .on('headers', (headers) => {
        console.log(headers)
    })
    .on('data', (data) => {
        if (count >= maxLines) {
            fsStream.unpipe(csvStream);
            csvStream.end();
            fsStream.destroy();             
        } else {
            console.log(data);
            count++;
        }
    });
```

Basically you just count each read line and when the max is reached, you `unpipe` the csv-stream from the fs-stream, then `end` the csv-stream and finally `destroy` the fs-stream.

Comment: but then he needs to get the result out of his `exports.checkFileFormat` function

Comment: Thank you @eol ! It didn't solve my issue, but it's more correct then my first attempt with a check inside `.on('data', (data) => {...}`